# Does fire shield negate invisibility?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, invisibility

Since fire shield makes you glow and invisibility only extend to things you're wearing or carrying. People can more or less see you. Does it then cancel out invisibility?

Fire shield:

> Thin and wispy flames wreathe your body for the Duration, shedding bright light in a 10-foot radius

Invisibility:

> Anything the target is wearing or carrying is invisible as long as it is on the target's person.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

### You are still invisible

You emit bright light in a 10 foot radius, but this light does not cancel the *Invisible* condition. In terms of the game mechanics, you still can't be targeted by spells requiring the caster to see the target, and all attacks against you still get disadvantage.

### Your enemies knows your location though

Jeremy Crawford, a D&D 5e game designer, [says](https://twitter.com/jeremyecrawford/status/684181987150594048) that invisibility doesn't make you disappear:

> The invisibility spell doesn't automatically hide you; you still make noise.

So even when you become invisible, enemies can still reveal your location and attack you, with disadvantage. Usually DM asks for a Perception/Stealth opposed check in order to resolve the outcome (are you hidden or not).

However, if you're emitting light, it's reasonable to assume you can't hide your presence at all. Your enemies will know where are you located (in what square, if your DM uses a grid) and can attack this place (this square). But you still get all the rest benefits of being invisible.

Comment: Would the "thin and wispy flames wreathe your body" be visible, or would only the bright light be visible?

Comment: @GuillaumeF. does it really matter?

Comment: It would make your answer more easily generalizable to other spells if you could make that distinction. It also matters in the rare case where the Hallow spell is used to create an area of darkness.

Comment: @GuillaumeF. the rules don't say. Ask your GM for an adjudication, it's her/his job. A GM might say the Invisibility spell negates all visual effects, and honestly I see no problem with that.