# Moonbeam's Ghostly Light vs Invisibility

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, invisibility

What happens when [Moonbeam](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/moonbeam) targets an area that contains an invisible creature? Moonbeam says

> When a creature enters the spell’s area for the first time on a turn or starts its turn there, it is engulfed in ghostly flames that cause searing pain (...)

Would this negate the invisibility of the creature(s) with the area of effect of the Moonbeam?

Comment: Highly related: [Can "Shield of Faith" counter invisibility?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/178948/23547)

Answer (score 8):

### Moonbeam won't remove the benefits of invisibility

Moonbeam does not say the flames render invisible creatures visible or remove the benefits of their invisibility. Compare this for example with [Faerie Fire](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/faerie-fire), which outlines the creature in colored light, and explicitly says:

> the affected creature or object can't benefit from being invisible.

Moonbeam does not say that. If it was automatic, *faerie fire* would not need to say it either. This is in line with the principle that spells [do only what they say](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/107637/what-is-the-source-of-the-spells-do-only-what-they-say-they-do-rules-interpret?r=SearchResults&s=1%7C175.8271) they do.

You can imagine this as the flames not giving off real light, for example (they are ghostly, after all), or maybe as the flames also being made invisible, if you like.

One benefit of invisibility is that you can hide in plain sight. The image of invisible creatures being outlined by ghostly flames, and thereby not hidden any more even though they themselves remain invisible is pretty cool and also seems logical, so ask your DM how they handle it. They might rule otherwise.

Comment: If you are asking your DM, some of the things I might suggest are asking if the light briefly reveals them, so you know the square they are in and they might have to use another action to hide, or asking if they can roll a con save to avoid saying 'ouch' thus also revealing the square they are in. These aren't in the rules, but can be flavourful depending upon the DM you have.

Comment: @Groody the Hobgoblin. The DM ruled that it did. We were just curious. 

I think if I where to do it, I'd probably make the characters with LoS to the invisible creature take a perception check vs the spell DC of the caster to see if they notice for each round the  invisible creature was damaged.